# How to query for appointment items that have recipients?

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'd like to query the calendar for items that are meetings between multiple people (at least two people) and not items that are used just as placeholders for a single person (such as blocking off time to perform a solitary task).

I'm trying to query for any calendar item where the recipients list is NOT empty, assuming if there are recipients then there's at least one person other than the organizer.

Here's a snippet of what I have now, which returns all calendar items:

```
$filter = "[MessageClass]='IPM.Appointment'"
$Appointments =  $calendarFolder.Items
$Appointments.restrict($filter)
```

I assume I have to adjust the $filter string (this is in PowerShell).

Answer (score 0):

Create a restriction on the `MeetingStatus` property - you want 3 (`olMeetingReceived`) or 1 (`olMeeting`)